# How to link libraries properly using CMakeLists.txt for MinGW?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw

I have been pulling out of my hair because of CMakelists.txt. I would like to create a C++ application with GLFW, GLEW libraries, using MinGW and CLion IDE.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17.3)
project(imguiTask)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_compile_options(-DGLEW_NO_GLU)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        src/main.cpp
        src/imgui.cpp
        src/imgui_draw.cpp
        src/imgui_widgets.cpp
        )

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC includes)

add_library(libraries STATIC IMPORTED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw3)
```

[image: File structure]

I placed the needed libraries in the `libraries` folder as you can see in the picture. The folder is located in the project root. It is giving me the following error:

```
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglfw3
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [imguiTask.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/imguiTask.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/imguiTask.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [imguiTask] Error 2
```

It seeems to me, that it does not search in the folder I specified. I don't know why.

Comment: "It seeems to me, that it does not search in the folder I specified." - I don't see which line of your `CMakeLists.txt` specifies `libraries` directory for search libraries in it. Such settings are normally performed by `link_directories` or `target_link_directories` (Note, that the first one should be issued **before** `add_executable`/`add_library` you want to affect).

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed it.